# Java code, issue interpreting this piece of code

Tags: java, python, matrix

I need to translate the following piece of code into python, however i cannot understand these libraries / the way they use it. I have like zero background in java.

```
public static double modelLikelihood(Matrix mat) {
        double likelihood = 0;
          for (int i = 0; i < mat.numCols(); ++i)
          {
            likelihood += Math.exp(mat.getQuick(mat.numRows() - 1, i));
          }
        return likelihood;
      }
```

This part `mat.getQuick(mat.numRows() - 1, i)` I dont get it, I mean i don't understand what is he/she trying to do there.

Comment: I don't think anyone even has a remote possibility of "getting it" without you providing the `getQuick()` method...not even Gosling himself.

Comment: The part you extracted uses a 3rd party library: http://incanter.org/docs/parallelcolt/api/cern/colt/matrix/tdouble/DoubleMatrix2D.html#getQuick%28int,%20int%29 The method simply returns the value at `(row, col)` without any boundary checking.